# get fcm token in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, task

i am trying to implement fcm in my xamarin.forms app. so i am planning to use dependency service on each platform to get the token and save it in my database. i found that this `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` is deprecated. so i have to use this instead `var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>(); var token = instanceIdResult.Token;`

the thing is that i am not figuring out how to put in the code. i tried this:

GetToken.cs in my xamarin.forms app:

```
 public interface GetToken
    {
        Task <string> get_token();
    }
```

and this in my xamarin.android

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(gettoken))]
namespace App8.Droid
{
    internal class gettoken : GetToken
    {
 public Task<string> get_token()
        {
            Task<string> t = Task.Run(() => tokenToget());
            return t;



        }
async private Task<string> tokenToget()
        {
            var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>();
            var token = instanceIdResult.Token;
            return token;
        }
}
```

and implemented the service this way in my mainactivity.xaml.cs

```
Task<string> token = DependencyService.Get<GetToken>().get_token();
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Token: {token.Result}");
```

but the app stops. how can i use the code to return the token. note that when i don't use a task and just use it this way (use void as a return type and only call the depedency from the xamarin.forms as `DependencyService.Get<GetToken>().get_token();`)

```
async public void get_token()
        {

            var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>();
            var token = instanceIdResult.Token;
            Log.Debug("token", "Refreshed token: " + token);


        }
```

it works. so the problem seems to be in the way i am trying to use the task or something like that. what should i do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare your interface

```
public interface IToken
{
    Task <string> GetToken();
}
```

then implement it

```
public class Token : IToken
{
  public async Task<string> GetToken()
  {
      var instanceIdResult = await FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetInstanceId().AsAsync<IInstanceIdResult>();
      var token = instanceIdResult.Token;
      return token;
  }
}
```